# C# PrintPreviewDialog - How to change a background?

Tags: c#, printing

I have a PrintPreviewDialog. By default, the document to be printed is being shown on the white sheet. Is it possible to change the background from that white sheet to a custom image?

> EDIT
>
> I've figured it out - I had to
>   DrawImage on the PrintedDocument.

Comment: If you've figured it out, post your answer as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out - I had to DrawImage on the PrintedDocument.

Answer (score 0):

If check MDSN there is a [back color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog.backcolor.aspx) property. But it is mentioned like

> This API supports the .NET Framework
>   infrastructure and is not intended to
>   be used directly from your code.

You can do something like inherit from PrintPreviewDialog, and try changing the back color property of the new class. (I am not sure its a good method or it will work or not)